# Addition of elements within two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need some tips with my homework. I would appreciate any tips.

The objective is to create a two dimensional array where column 1 is the segment ID and column 2 is the segment value. 6 segments. User will be asked to enter each value for each ID.

```
[ 0   3               
  1   2
  2   1
  3   5
  4   2
  5   3 ]
```

User will enter any 3 ID's: e.g. 012 and each corresponding value will be added to the next.
So 035 would equal 3+5+3 = 11.

What would be a good way to go about this, and what loop would best suit this?
I understand how arrays work but I'm struggling to wrap my head around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any loops are necessarily involved and the array doens't need to be two-dimensional. I'm assuming that the user choices correspond to the indices of the array (e.g. 0 - 6). Once you get the three inputs from the user, you can just reference the array elements directly. For example:

```
int segments[6];
segments[0] = 3;
segments[1] = 2;
segments[2] = 1;
segments[3] = 5;
segments[4] = 2;
segments[5] = 3;

int firstUserChoice = // parse from input
int secondUserChoice = // parse from input
int thirdUserChoice = // parse from input

int sum = segments[firstUserChoice] + segments[secondUserChoice] + segments[thirdUserChoice];
```

Comment: int segments[6]; wouldn't compile

Comment: Yes, two dimensions is not necessary. I will try your suggestion now. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry... I'm writing pseudocode. What language are you execpting? This won't necessarily compile out of the box.

Comment: there will be only one input from the user, not three separate ones.

Comment: I'm unclear if you're asking for help about how to get the input or just the general logic of the data structure and how to reference its values.

Comment: Sorry, the general logic of the problem.

Comment: Yes, pardon me, user will enter 3 inputs not one. I will try this now.